# what login should I keep for app (for appstore approval)

Tags: ios, authentication, appstore-approval

I have created an app for Real estate where there are 4 sections.

1. Home (where list of rent and sale are shown)
2. Admin (admin can login and enter data)
3. Search
4. More

Now I will be uploading this app on the app store.

For Admin section, what username and password should I keep so that Apple team can login into those for review purpose. Once approved, I will delete that user.

Is there default username and password for Apple for review purpose?

I am asking as while submitting the app, I cannot write username and password anywhere so that we can tell to Review team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide yourself what is the username and password you want Apple to use for review. When you submit the app or update the app, there is a section where you can supply those information, under App Review Information:

[image: Demo account information]